# Using Java need to create a hashmap that is populated with data from a file

Tags: java, input, hashmap, hashset, iteration

I am trying to figure out a way to iterate through a file and generate a new hashset based on the first column.  The value in the first column will server as the key in a hashmap.  So for example, say I have a file that contains the following:

- element1     value1
- element1     value2
- element1     value3
- element2     value1
- element2     value2

I need to have a hashmap with a key of element1 and values of value1 value2 and value3.  The next key will be of element2 and values of value1 and value2.  Use of the hashset of type User is required.

I can get through element1 and populate it fine.  But when it gets to element2 I am not sure how to grab that information without erasing the entire hashset.  Or what would be the best way to generate a new hashset dynamically as the values of the file are not static.

Of course any help will be appreciated.

`
        public class User {

```
public T Username;
String key = null;
public HashSet<User> friends = new HashSet<User>();
public HashSet<User> temps = new HashSet<User>();
HashMap<String, HashSet<User>> map = new HashMap<String, HashSet<User>>();


public HashSet readFile(){

    String temp = null;

    try
    {
        File f = new File("file.txt");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(f);

        String line = null;
        line = input.nextLine();
        int count = 0;

        while (input.hasNextLine()){    
        String parts[] = line.split("\t");
        temp = parts[0];



            if(!parts[0].equals(temp)){

                friends.add(new User(parts[1]));
                map.put(parts[0], friends);
                //here I had friends.clear(); thinking to clear out 
                                    //the set and start to populate with the values
                                    //of new hashset but it clears set for all keys.
            }else if(parts[0].equals(temp)){
                friends.add(new User(parts[1]));

                map.put(temp, friends);

            }

            temp = parts[0];
            line = input.nextLine();

        }


    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e){
        System.out.println("File not found");
    }


    return friends;


}


public void setKey(String fKey){

    key = fKey;
    //return key;

}


public static void outputSet(HashSet<User> set){

    Iterator<User> i = set.iterator();
    while (i.hasNext()){
        System.out.print(i.next() + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}

public void buildMap(String fKey, HashSet<User> mappy){

    map.put(fKey, mappy);   
    System.out.println(map);

}


@Override
public String toString() {
    return ("" + Username +"");
}
```

}
`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want `friends = new HashSet<User>();` instead of `friends.clear()` to create a new list. But this code is really messy, I suggest you head over to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) to get help with cleaning it.

Comment: I appreciate your feedback.  When I insert friends = new HashSet<User>(); I get a hashmap value of:  {element2=[value1, value3, value1, value2], element1=[value1, value3, value1, value2]}   Which isn't quite what I want.  haha...I know my code must look atrocious. I'm in "please just work" mode at the moment.  will clean up after I get it functioning.

Comment: Hmm, I can see a lot more that isn't working. I'll see what I can write.